# Comparando um valor de uma tabela, com intervalo em outra tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Sou muito leigo em Access, porém preciso utilizá-lo para resolver um problema.

Supondo que eu tenha duas Tabelas (só pra exemplificar):

Tabela A:

```
CEP INICIO | CEP FINAL | CDD | CTC
20000-000  | 29999-999 | CDD Exemplo 1 | CTC Exemplo 1
30000-000  | 39999-999 | CDD Exemplo 2 | CTC Exemplo 2
40000-000  | 49999-999 | CDD Exemplo 3 | CTC Exemplo 3
```

Tabela B:

```
NOME | CEP
Fulano | 31564-888
Joãozinho | 22559-010
Pedrinho | 44411-000
```

Como posso fazer pra saber qual o valor do CDD e do CTC referente às pessoas da tabela B??

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma nova consulta `(menu Criar > Design da Consulta)` e, no modo design `(clique com o botão direito e selecione Modo SQL)`, insira o código abaixo:

```
SELECT cliente.cep, cliente.*, preco.*
FROM cliente, preco
WHERE (((cliente.cep)>=[preco]![cepinico] And (cliente.cep)<=[preco]![cepfim]));
```

Depois é só executar

Comment: Vou tentar procurar como rodar esse comando, obrigado.

Comment: Não sei como rodar este comando!

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Porém ele me pede para "inserir valor do parâmetro"...